# Architecture ElasticSearch (Advices)

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, logstash

I'm a student and I have to build an ELK architecture to process gigas of logs per day in real time.
For this, I have at my disposal 2 servers on a geographic site and 2 other in an other geographic site.

For now I have chosen the following architecture :

First site : 
VM1 : Master Node 1 / None Data + Logstash primary 
VM2 : Master Node 2 / Data + Kibana

Second site : 
VM3 : Logstash secondary (if the primary breaks down) 
VM4 : Master Node 3 / Data + Kibana

I would need your advice if it is a good architecture or not ! Thank you very much !

Comment: What does it mean 'process'? What are you going to do with those logs? Search through? What are the typical search queries, use-cases etc?

Comment: Any reason why you chose to have 2 master nodes in the first site?

Comment: Vladislav, Logs will be transmitted to logstash to extract important information (several grok filters). These are logs of a call center, so I want to do mainly statistics on kibana (calls transmitted, not transmitted ...) and have details on specific calls (call flow)

Comment: At first I had only two node. But I added a node on the first site only to avoid split brain. I put it all three in master so that it can be independent in case of breakdown of one or two knots. The goal is that elasticsearch is always functional.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clusters spanning multiple regions are not supported in Elasticsearch. This is related to the latency, reliability, and throughput of the network connection between regions. This is a common reason for problems with a cluster.
2. Having 3 master-eligable nodes is good.
3. Having multiple Logstash instances is good. Though you can configure both on the sender side and they will round robin between them. No need for a primary and a secondary.

Comment: Thanks for your advices ! Just a little question : If I make 2 clusters one in each regions and use tribe node to connect them, It's a good idea or the best is to make all the node in one site ?

Comment: You need 3 master-eligable nodes to be highly available and avoid split-brain situations. So probably one region would be better if you only want to use up to 4 servers. Tribe node will work, but will be replaced with Cross Cluster Search in the future. Note that only Tribe supports Kibana at the moment — will be added to Cross Cluster Search soon(ish).

Comment: Thank you very much Xeraa for your advices ! I will group the differents Data node in one site.

So if I start with this It seems better ?

First site : 
VM1 : Master Node 1/None Data + Logstash 1 
VM2 : Logstash 2 (work at the same time as logstash 1)

Second site : 
VM3 : Master Node 2 / Data + Kibana 
VM4 : Master Node 3 / Data + Kibana

Comment: All the nodes of one cluster should be in one region (a single cluster should not span multiple region) — that includes master nodes. Also you wouldn't gain any resiliency from this setup; if the second site goes down, your cluster will be down.

Comment: Okay ! My objectif is that elasticsearch are Always functional. 
So if I have 3 data / master node and One logstash in the first site, How could I replicate the data in the 2nd site in case the first one breaks down ?

Comment: "always" is a very strong argument and I'm not sure the cost and complexity are worth it for a logging use case. There might be a nicer solution in 6.x, but right now you would need to distribute the data with Kafka or a similar system between the regions and have 2 independent clusters.